# Setting and removing the onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to remove the onclick attribute from the div "#link". It will not remove. It also will not work with setting an attribute for onclick. Anything that seems to edit onclick doesn't seem to effect it. I need it to remove the attribute of "of onclick" and set it to another one. Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var attribute = $('#link').attr("onclick");
  var linklength = (attribute.split("'").length - 1);
  if (linklength > 5) {
    $('#link').removeAttr("onclick");
        $('#link')[0].setAttribute('onclick', 'test');
    console.log(attribute);
    console.log(linklength);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="link" onclick="skinPopup('UserDirectory','for name ','#userBio');">

</div>
<p id="title">Te'st</p>
```

Comment: Do not use setAttribute to add events. There is addEventListener!

Comment: `$('#link')[0].onclick=null;`

Comment: Neither seem to do anything. https://jsfiddle.net/w0mcr5vh/7/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, as you already using jQuery you could simplify things. Something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var $link = $("#link");
 function skinPopup(directory, statement, id){
  console.log(directory, statement, id);
 }
 
 $link.on('click', function(){
  skinPopup('UserDirectory','for name ','#userBio');
 });
 
 //removing click event after 3s
 setTimeout(function(){
  $link.addClass('red');
  $link.off('click');
  // attaching mouseover and mouseout event
  $link.on('mouseover', function(){
   $(this).removeClass('red');
  }).on('mouseout', function(){
   $(this).addClass('red');
  })
 }, 3000)
   
});
```

```css
.red{
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="link">
Link
</div>
<p id="title">Te'st</p> 
 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note, instead of removing `click` event on condition I removed it after a particular time, you could add condition based on your requirements. Both `attribute` and `linklength` seemed unnecessary, that's why I removed it.

To learn more about event listeners

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener
http://api.jquery.com/on/ 
http://api.jquery.com/off/

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.